# Errors in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, compilation

I'm having problems while executing a stored procedure in Oracle.

Below is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure xxxlist
    (yyyid in NUMBER)    
IS
    xid number(6);
    cursor c1 is select distinct xxxID from MXS.Y where YID=yyyid;
BEGIN
IF NOT c1%ISOPEN THEN 
    OPEN c1;
END IF;
LOOP
    FETCH c1 into xid;
    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(xid));
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND; 
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;   
END;
```

When I create the stored procedure, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

I execute the below command to provide me more details on the above abstract error message.

```
SHO ERR;
```

I get the below details in response to the above command:

```
Errors for PROCEDURE XXXLIST:
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/18     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/52     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Now, I understand that there is a problem with the table name or sql query itself. So, I try to execute the SQL query alone, seperately, outside the PRODECURE, to see what is wring with the table or query.

```
select distinct xxxID from MXS.Y where YID=yyyid;
```

But, I do not find any issues with the above query. The query runs fine and I get proper result.

So, I do not know why the procedure is having problems while executing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible explanation is that the account you are running in has been granted access to the table through a role.  In Oracle, access granted through roles affects standalone SQL statements but not SQL statements embedded in PL/SQL.

If this is the case, the owner of the table (or a DBA) would have to grant select access on the table directly to your account:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mxs.y TO <account>;
```